# Is the function synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: javascript

Is the below function synchronous or asynchronous?
Can someone tell me?
It is a very simple function?

```
let production = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("production has started");

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("the fruit has been chopped");

      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`${stocks.liquid[0]} and ${stocks.liquid[0]} was added`);

        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(`icescream was placed on ${stocks.holder[0]}`);

          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`icescream was placed on ${stocks.holder[0]}`);

            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log(`${stocks.toppings[0]} was added as toppings`);

              setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("Serve icescream");
              }, 3000);
            }, 3000);
          }, 2000);
        }, 1000);
      }, 1000);
    }, 2000);
  }, 0000);
};

order(0, production);
```

Was watching a youtube tutorial and became confused?

Comment: setTimeout() is async, so... yes?

Comment: You might want to consider some points from [meta-chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56744141#56744141) for your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a series of async functions, they have an "order" by the length of timeout defined. But the whole thing remains asynchronous.

If you were to run any synchronous code in the next line after the call for this, say `console.log('test')`, it would print before any of the code in your snippet.